# how to open a webpage in full screen with only title bar

Tags: javascript

how to open a webpage in Internet Explorer so that when i double click on that it opens up full screen with only the title-bar.

Comment: sorry , when u double click on the html icon

Comment: when i double click on a html icon i want it to open up full screen with only the title bar

Comment: i think no 1 knows the answer.....hmm ok go to youtube.com and search for "PEPSI-we will rock you " and see ..nice female voice..have fun and keep thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var popup = window.open(location.href, "_blank", 
    "menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,status=0,directories=0,width=" + 
    screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height);
popup.moveTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: do i hav to type these inside <script language="javascript">
 </script>

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var popup = window.open(location.href, "_blank", 
    "menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,status=0,directories=0,width=" + 
    screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height);
popup.moveTo(0, 0);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ur answer is correct but it there is 1 prob it keeps on asking run activex or not 
...just execute and try

Comment: Pages loaded from the filesystem may not use JS by default in IE, for rather sad and pointless reasons. Look up the “mark of the web” for how to get around that. In any case, most browsers today will ignore some of the popup options and/or `moveTo`, for security reasons.

Comment: @subanki Yes you have to put them in script tags - any javascript code in an html page should be put inside script tags. And don't just put inside script tag - put this inside a function inside a script tag and call the function on the click of a button. As @bobince said, IE will throw this warning for local files with js in them. It'll work fine when your page is hosted in a server. Watchout for popup blockers though. You might be able to get around some of them if you call this from onclick of some control on the html page - basically it must be initiated by user action.